# COM Library .Net

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6

I have built an application in .Net. now i need to make the same application in vb6.
however there are some method in .Net application which i want to reuse in vb6 application.

To achieve this i am using .Net COM libraries.

Now my question.

- Do we need .Net framework to use COM library in vb6 ?

E.g : i have a PC in which no framework is installed. and i run my VB6 application which is using .Net COM library. so i have to install .Net framework on that PC or it will work fine without any issue ?

Detailed information would be great appreciable.

Comment: For further information read some of the other questions about [VB6 and COM-interop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/com-interop+vb6)

Answer (score 2):

The .NET COM library is a .NET program, so yes, it will require the appropriate .NET runtime to be installed on the PC that will run it.